# Signed/unsigned representation of ints in decompiled code in Hopper

Tags: decompilation, hopper

Hopper allows you to change the representation of numbers in the disassembly window so that:

```
0000be84         str        r3, [r11, #0xfffffff0]
```

becomes:

```
0000be84         str        r3, [r11, #-0x10]
```

This doesn't carry over into the decompiled code though:

```
r3 = *(r11 + 0xffffffffffffffd8);
```

Whilst it's not a major thing, it would be nice for the representation to be carried across.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible now; feel free to open an issue on Hopper's [bugtracker](http://www.hopperapp.com/bugtracker/).